# For loop inside another for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Can't wrap my head around why this piece of JavaScript code outputs 100.

```
var num = 0;

for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < 10; j++) {
        num++;
    }
}

alert(num); // 100
```

Comment: Cause it's double loop 10x10 = 100

Comment: The inner loop will be 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 10.

The outer loop will be 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 = 100.

Comment: When i=0, j loops 10 times, when i=1, j loops ten times again. Continue this another 8 times, and you get 100. 10 a loop of 10 = 100 times.

Comment: Please be more specific. What about this code do you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this, you can watch the behavior of `i`, `j`, and `num`:

```
var num = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        alert("i = "+i+", j = "+j+", num = "+num);
        num++;
    }
}
alert(num);
```

`i` iterates 10 times, `j` iterates to 10 `i` times, and so `num` is incremented 100 times (10 * 10)

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop runs `10` times for every iteration of the outer loop. Since the outer loop runs `10` times as well, the inner loop runs `10 x 10` times, which is `100`.

Consider one iteration of the inner loop. It runs `10` times, right? Since `num` is `0` initially, after the inner loop runs the first time, `num` will be `10`. I mentioned earlier that the inner loop runs `10` times for each iteration of the outer loop, so after each iteration of the outer loop, `num` is basically incremented by `10`. This means that you eventually end up with `num` equal to `100`.

Answer (score 0):

It does the inner loop 10 times.

```
    for (var j=0; j < 10; j++) {
        num++; // 10
    }
```

Then it does it 10 more times because it's in a for loop.

```
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
   // each time this runs you will add 10.
}
```

In the end the inner for loop will run 100 times. 10 times every time it is called. It's called 10 times. 10 * 10 = 100.

Answer (score 0):

For loops loop x times.

```
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    count++;
//count = 10
```

So Sequential loops ADD

```
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    count++;
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    count++;
//count = 17 // 7 (first) + 10 (second)
```

But loops Within loops MULTIPLY (because each INNER loop is executed for each OUTER loop)

```
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        count++;
//count = 40 // 4 (outer) * 10 (inner)
```

So to calculate loop iterations multiply inner by outer, or for sequential add the first then the second

Answer (score -1):

The inner loop is executed 10 times.
The inner loop executes 10 times.
The inner loop execution add 1 to num;
10*10 of adding 1 yields 100